# Edit Fields in Closed Opportunity

Tags: opportunity, fields, locking

I've given a Profile read/write access over several fields on the Opportunity level. However, because the record is locked after Closing Lost or Won, they cannot edit the fields. How can I choose to exclude fields from being locked upon Closure of an Opportunity, or better yet, how can I specifically allow fields to be edited in a locked, closed Opportunity? Thank you.

Comment: This is not possible. Only admins and users with Modify All access on the object can edit locked records, but they would be able to edit any fields they are allowed to edit on page layout.

Comment: When you say edit "on page layout" what do you mean? This Profile does not have Modify All access on the Opp, but I don't understand the "on page layout" phrase.

Comment: It's when you click Edit button.

Comment: @Oleksiy, so there is no inline editing, unless one has Modify All access?

Comment: It has to do with the locked records - as I said earlier `Only admins and users with Modify All access on the object can edit locked records`.

Comment: @Oleksiy, is it possible to designate which fields are not locked on a locked record? Is is possible to, perhaps using a permission set, unlock specific fields for a group of users to be actioned after an Opportunity closes? Thank you.

Comment: Locking is done on a record level and is separate from the fields access. You can [have a validation(s) to restrict some fields modification in a specific stages](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/119638/12440), but this has to be done prior the locking.

Comment: @Oleksiy, so there isn't a way to ensure overwrite access to a specific group of fields after the record is locked as a whole? Absolutely no way?

Comment: are you willing to allow the user to attempt to change the fields + save and then get an error if changing a "locked" field value?  If yes, you could define a set of field names allowed for change in a custom setting and then handle this in a simple trigger. Trigger would be written once, custom settings define allowed fields and can change over time

Comment: @cropredy, I don't think that works for us, and I would rather not have them hit the error.

Answer (score 3):

[This question](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hFRlAAM) on the success site describes some ways that you can have certain fields editable in a "locked" stage, but they all require customization or new record types.

If you want to edit the locked fields without any customization, users will have to have the "Modify All" permission or be an Admin, as Oleksiy has said. I don't believe there's another way.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but I'd like to know if we can do it in a way other than granting Modify All or new record types. I do not want to grant modify all, but will if I have to. I cannot add to our Record Types, given how many we have already and the permutations of additional types I'd have to create.

Comment: @TamimJ I understand, sometimes they're just not an option. I think in this case then, it would be between a new Visualforce page, and Modify All. cropredy has a good answer about the VF page, if those are possible for you. This link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_tabs.htm has some more detailed info about that.

Answer (score 3):

Some solutions

**Use record types , page layouts and profiles**

When Opportunity becomes Closed Won, have a workflow/process flow change the record type to `ClosedWon`

Create a page layout `ClosedWonLayout` and make "locked-from-edits" fields on layout read only.  Benign fields can remain editable.

Assign `ClosedWonLayout` page layout + `ClosedWon` RecordType to profiles that shouldn't be able to edit closed won oppos

Assign normal page layout + `ClosedWon` recordtype to profiles that should be able to edit closed won oppos

**Visualforce**

You'll need to create a VF page called `ClosedWonOppo_Restricted`.  Override the standard Edit and View buttons to go to this page.

In the VF page action, redirect to either the standard edit/view pages if not closed Won or if user is unrestricted from edits. Otherwise, redirect to the VF page. You'll do this with a `URLFOR(...)`

The VF page should conditionally allow inline edits only on those fields that are benign

Comment: We have too many existing record types, along with renewals, to be able to consider a new record type for each of them to house this unlocking of the record.

Comment: @TamimJ - you are sort of between a rock and a hard place. Until SFDC delivers on conditional rendering within standard page layouts, you'll need to go the VR route and users will self-train as they discover they can't edit fields after closed won.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answers, this will only be possible via Visualforce. @cropredy's solution works fine, I am just going to give one alternative that is slightly more user friendly.

1. Create a visualforce page and put it inline in your current page layout(s)
2. On an output panel, put something like: `rendered="o.IsClosed"`
3. Put the input fields and a save (though you probably want to call it something different) button inside the output panel for the ones you want to be editable
4. Create an apex class and mark it `Without Sharing` and create a method that will take an opportunity and update it.
5. In your page controller, create pass the opportunity (with the updated fields) to the Without Sharing method

Here are some resources to help you with the page:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005105&language=en_US (hot to embed a page)
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm (how to build a controller extension, which is how you are going to get your custom method in there)
[When to use with sharing or without sharing?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11768/when-to-use-with-sharing-or-without-sharing) (some tips about With/Without Sharing)

Comment: A few issues with this solution: 1) embedded page will take space regardless it's rendered or not 2) each user would be able to edit the fields, or you'd have to develop some logic