# How to lock date field in opportunity?

Tags: opportunity, validation-rule, customization

I have few scenarios for locking the date

1. If Closed:Won – Date locked
2. If Stage changed to ‘Closed:Lost’ or ‘Declined’ from Closed:Won then date is changed to the date of that activity and locked again.
3. If Stage goes from Closed:Lost, Declined or Closed:Won to anything pre Closed Won then date is unlocked and can be edited as usual.

How can I implement the above logic?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few different ways to solve this, I'll list 2:

1. Using [Validation Rules](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000guZOAAY), you can write a formula to prevent the field being edited based on the current and previous answers (look at Steve's answer).
2. If your Org has the capability, you could write a Before Trigger and check both the old and new values, and decline or allow the update that way.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create validation rule:

`AND(
 OR(
  ISPICKVAL(Stage, 'Closed:Lost'),
  ISPICKVAL(Stage, 'Declined'),
  ISPICKVAL(Stage, 'Closed:Won')
 ),
 ISCHANGED(CloseDate)
)`

With a notification *"Date change is not allowed in 'Closed:Lost', 'Declined, and  'Closed:Won' stages"*

2. Create a Workflow with Evaluation Criteria *Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited*:

`AND(
 OR(
  ISPICKVAL(Stage, 'Closed:Lost'),
  ISPICKVAL(Stage, 'Declined')
 ),
 ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Stage), 'Closed:Won')
 ),`

with Field Update action: `CloseDate = TODAY()`

Comment: Hi do I need to create validation on stage (picklist field) or Close date field?

Comment: Validation formula itself has all fields you need for validation. If you are asking where to show validation error - it depends, in your case I'd show error message on CloseDate, as this is the field you want to lock

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Do I need to create Workflow too? because it is allowing me to edit close date even thought i use validation rule?

Comment: Yes, you need WF to set CloseDate to today's date, stated in your 2nd scenario.

Comment: It is throwing me an error Error: Function PRIORVALUE may not be used in this type of formula. I tried using ISCHANGED still giving me error

Comment: I'm sorry, you have to select this Evaluation Criteria: **Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited**. I just updated my answer.

Comment: Even Though I applied your validation rule and Workflow, Closedate is not locked . please let me know how to make close date not editable for the above conditions

Comment: I tried  Evaluation Criteria: Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited but it is not working

Comment: If I  am using  Evaluation Criteria: Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited it is giving Error: Function PRIORVALUE may not be used in this type of formula . pls help

Comment: There is no such a thing that could make the  field not editable on a condition. The way I described does not allow to save the modified field, or will populate today's date as you have in your logic

Comment: But it is saving modified date

Comment: @sai Let me know in what stage it allows to save modified date. Please double check if your picklist values for `Stage` are exactly the same as you have them listed: 'Closed:Lost’, ‘Declined’, and 'Closed:Won'